# mysql Error Code: 1130

Tags: mysql

ayer funcionaba bien mi mysql
y ahora q lo inicio y quiero entrar a mi bd
me sale este error

`host localhost is not allowed to connect to this mysql server`

y en detalles de error

> Error Code: 1130
> This error occurs because you don't have a permission to connect to MySQL server from your host. Please contact your database administrator or, if you have access to MySQL server with grant privilege, you can use the GRANT statement to add a new user. For example, the following command will give full access from your host to the user:
> /*!50003 CREATE USER 'user'@'user_host'*/;
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'user_host' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';

Comment: Mira aca http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857446/error-1130-in-mysql (esta eninglés) ilustra loque debes hacer; como mencionas algo ocurrio que (digamos) "revoco" los permisos para el usuario que usas desde la compu.

Answer (score 1):

En tu host debes de crear el usuario asignandole las diferentes segmentaciones de las rutas por las cuales podrá accesar como lo son, "%", "127.0.0.1", "localhot" y "0.0.0.0", por ejemplo:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Con esa estructura deberías de poder iniciar sesión desde algún otro servidor remoto.